# Morse code to English: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm attempting to create a program in Java that converts morse code into English. In this case, letters are separated by one space and words are separated by three spaces:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReverseMorseCodeProgram {
  public static void main(String[] args) { //Converts Morse Code into English

  System.out.println("Enter the Morse Code to be converted to English (letters and spaces only, no numbers or punctuation):");
  String sentence = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine(); //Input is converted into String
  char[] dotdash = sentence.toCharArray(); //String is converted into char[]
  String[] words = new String[30]; //String array where char[] is converted into morse code letters
  int y = 0;
  int x = 0;

  while (dotdash[x] < dotdash.length) { //Converts char[] into String[]

    while (dotdash[x] != ' ') { //loops until a space is encountered
      words[y] = words[y] + dotdash[x]; //adds chars to String in array
      x = x + 1; //goes to next char in array
    }

    if ((dotdash[x+1] == ' ') && (dotdash[x+2] == ' ')) { //determines whether there are three spaces in a row
      words[y+1] = "   "; //adds "   " as next string in array
      y = y + 2; //moves to string after "   "
      x = x + 3; //moves to char after the three spaces
    }
    else { //if there's only one space
      y = y + 1; //moves to next string in String[]
      x = x + 1; //moves to next char in char[]
    }
  }

  char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', //English alphabet array
    'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
    'm', 'n', 'o', 'p',
    'q', 'r', 's', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x',
    'y', 'z', ' '};
  String[] morse = {".-", "-...", "-.-.", "-..", //morse code alphabet array
    ".", "..-.", "--.", "....",
    "..", ".---", "-.-", ".-..",
    "--", "-.", "---", ".--.",
    "--.-", ".-.", "...", "-",
    "..-", "...-", ".--", "-..-",
    "-.--", "--..", "   "};


  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { //repeats until end of String array
    for (int t = 0; t < 27; t++) { //goes through morse code array
      if (morse[t] == words[i]) { //compares morse code to each word in String array
        System.out.print(alphabet[t]); //prints equivalent english letter when match is found
      }
    }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I input the phrase "-- -.-- ..-. .- ...- --- ..- .-. .. - . -.-. --- .-.. --- .-. .. ... .-. . -..", I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 78
    at ReverseMorseCodeProgram.main(ReverseMorseCodeProgram.java:15)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Inputting a shorter string, such as "--" results in no output at all.

I'm fairly new to programming, and this has me stumped.

edit: I've changed the offending section from:

```
  while (dotdash[x] < dotdash.length) { //Converts char[] into String[]

    while (dotdash[x] != ' ') { //loops until a space is encountered
      words[y] = words[y] + dotdash[x]; //adds chars to String in array
      x = x + 1; //goes to next char in array
    }

    if ((dotdash[x+1] == ' ') && (dotdash[x+2] == ' ')) { //determines whether there are three spaces in a row
      words[y+1] = "   "; //adds "   " as next string in array
      y = y + 2; //moves to string after "   "
      x = x + 3; //moves to char after the three spaces
    }
    else { //if there's only one space
      y = y + 1; //moves to next string in String[]
      x = x + 1; //moves to next char in char[]
    }
  }
```

To the following:

```
  while (x < dotdash.length) { //Converts char[] into String[]

    while (dotdash[x] != ' ') { //loops until a space is encountered
      words[y] = words[y] + dotdash[x]; //adds chars to String in array
      x = x + 1; //goes to next char in array
    }

    if (((x+2) < dotdash.length) && ((y+1) < words.length)) { //ensures that dotdash[x+2] and (y+1) doesn't exceed their respective boundaries

      if ((dotdash[x+1] == ' ') && (dotdash[x+2] == ' ')) { //determines whether there are three spaces in a row
        words[y+1] = "   "; //adds "   " as next string in array
        y = y + 2; //moves to next string after "   "
        x = x + 3; //moves to next char after the three spaces
      }
      else { //if there's only one space
        y = y + 1; //moves to next string in String[]
        x = x + 1; //moves to next char in char[]
      }

    }

  }
```

However, the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error persists. I can't seem to spot where else I could be exceeding the array's boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

On line 15, change while (dotdash[x] < dotdash.length) to while (x < dotdash.length). dotdash[x] is the element of dotdash with index x. You don't want to compare that to the array's length, you want to compare the index (x) to the array's length.

There may be other issues, I didn't look beyond that one, because it's what's causing the exception.

On edit: After looking a little further, you have a number of places that an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException can occur. Any place you take an element of an array, so dotdash[x + 1], etc., if the element you're trying to get is beyond the end of the array, you'll get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, so you need to make sure x + 1 < dotdash.length before trying to get dotdash[x + 1], etc.

Comment: I've made a few changes (added in an edit to my post), but the error seems to be persisting...

Comment: The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException tells you exactly what line the exception is occurring on, so examine the code on that line to see how you could be referencing beyond the end of an array. I'm guessing it's going to be somewhere in the first inner while loop, where you don't check any lengths, ever.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (dotdash[x] < dotdash.length)
```

That doesn't make any sense (to me at first glance). The value in the array is not a number.

I think you meant:

```
while (x < dotdash.length)
```

So you can index all the entries in the array.

Of course once you do that you will now have problems with:

```
if ((dotdash[x+1] == ' ') && (dotdash[x+2] == ' '))
```

because "x+1" and "x+2" can be greater than the length of the array.

So that if statement can only be executed when x < dotdash.length - 2.

So you need to restructure you code a bit.